# How to get specific email record using `aws-sdk` `cloudwatch` for a custom date range period?

Tags: reactjs, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

Actually I tried to get email report data that was sent by an amazon SES.
By using cloudwatch api I can get the list of all emails reports with custom date range.
But, I need a specific email report with custom date range period.

```
cloudwatch.listMetrics(
{
   MetricName: 'Open',
   Dimensions: [
      { Name: 'ses:configuration-set', Value: 'CloudWatch-Default' },
      { Name: 'campaign' }
   ],
   Namespace: 'AWS/SES'
},
(err, data) => {
   console.log('errfrom getmetrsta send', err);
   console.log('list metrices Open', data);
});
```

by using listmetrics api I can get count of 1 click report even i have 10 click report for that email in my dashboard.

**Expected result:**

I need a list of all reports for single email.

**Actual result:**

I receives only a single report for a single email even it has 10 reports in the dashboard.